# Why are the checkboxes different on different devices?

Tags: launcher, user-interface

Why is there a difference in the look of the checkboxes between [this device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwBL3.png) and [this Samsung device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4AbHP.png)?

Is this affected by the launcher, in which case the reason is clear?

Comment: That images are kind of big for that I think.

Comment: Fair enough, I've inlined the imgur versions so that we're not relying on two third-party sites.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Theming is independent of the launcher, although both may be considered part of the UI; for example, the TouchWiz launcher and theme are elements of Samsung's TouchWiz UI.

My Samsung Vibrant is running a custom ROM called Bionix, and they've re-themed the device so my checkboxes look like this (perhaps the only thing I dislike about the ROM):

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I see. How can I change checkboxes (and anything else that goes with it)? Is it a different application than the Launcher?

Comment: What's the `(64)` thing in your screenshot? Looks mysterious.

Comment: @Francisc I don't know the specifics, but it involves editing various images in the ROM; on most phones you'd need root to do it.  I still have the TouchWiz launcher but the images and some color settings have been changed.  The `(64)` is my battery percentage.

Comment: Very Bionix I must say. Thank for the answer.

Comment: @Francisc: The drawables generally live in a `/system/framework/framework-res.apk` file (the pathing might be different depending on the device/ROM). [Here's a screenshot](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/16958605/framework-res-archive.png) of the drawable-hdpi folder in the `framework-res.apk` file that ships with CM7. The PNGs that I've outlined are the drawables used for the checkboxes, as a example. Editing can be a a little tedious, and has a tendency to cause bootloops (for me, at least...)